# install latest github release using npm

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I would like to install a node package directly from github.
I am able to use a command like this:
`npm install git://github.com/codeine-cd/codeineNodePeer.git#V0.0.1`

However, I would like to use the latest release, I have a tag for that but I cant write it in the git url (like `#latest`)

Is it possible to do that any other way?